# Angularjs: component module not available

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am definitely doing something wrong while trying to create a component in Angularjs. I am getting an error:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Any pointers would be helpful. Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/davidbrooks/nj3xLLwo/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    public foo(): string[] {
        return Object.keys(MyEnum).filter(k => {
            typeof MyEnum[k] === "number"
        }) as string[];
    }
```

[Here is the updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wjvopq1r/) .

Comment: Thanks, but it is still not working. I think I am doing something wrong with the way controller/module setup